# PySpark - Implement Cumulative Sum with Reset for Sessionizaiton

Tags: pyspark

I'm currently working on implementing a pseduo-sessionization workflow with the following logic:

1. The first session begins at the time of event 0, `t0`. It has a set duration of `w`.
2. All events between `t0` and `t0 + w` are included in the session.
3. The next session beings at the time of the first event after`t0 + w`.

An example of this with event times + a window of 5:

```
# Event Times
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 19, 20]
# Desired Sessions
[[0, 1, 3, 4],[6, 7], [12], [19, 20]]
```

I had hoped to accomplish this using windowing functions and the following approach:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# Create DF of "timestamps"
df = spark.range(100).select((100 * f.rand()).alias("time")).sort("time")

# Define Basic Window for Cumulative Time
window = Window.orderBy("time")

# Add Running Sum of 
time_delta = f.coalesce(f.col("time") - f.lag("time", 1).over(window), f.lit(0))
cumulative_time = f.sum(time_delta).over(window)
df_with_cumulative_time = df.withColumn("cumulative_time", cumulative_time)
df_with_cumulative_time.show()

# Cut down number of rows for clarity
+--------------------+-------------------+------+----------------------+
|                time|    cumulative_time|bucket|time_delta_partitioned|
+--------------------+-------------------+------+----------------------+
|   9.039619445312974|  9.014379183779287|     1|    1.5164663384277022|
|   13.97802483655507| 13.952784575021383|     2|                   0.0|
|  14.754876320965504| 14.729636059431817|     2|    0.7768514844104342|
|  16.389056026920525|  16.36381576538684|     3|                   0.0|# Wrong
|  16.850251524292048| 16.825011262758363|     3|   0.46119549737152354|
|  17.602828327880594|  17.57758806634691|     3|    0.7525768035885463|
+--------------------+-------------------+------+----------------------+
```

However, this yields the incorrect result. Bucket 2 starts at 13.9, and thus should group all values until 18.9 (makes sense as I'm diving global time by 5, but I can't figure out how to make this "stateful"). I've tried to be clever using various flooring / rounding functions, treating this as a modified "range intersect" problem by adding a time + window column and using those as start/end, but to no avail. Is there any way to accomplish stateful windowing like this? If not, I've resorted to using an ugly UDF that, after collecting all events into one huge list, does the following...

```
@f.udf
def pseudo_sessionize(events):
    if events:
        sessions_array = []
        threshold = events[0] + 5 # 5sec window
        left_edge = 0
        for i in range(len(events)):
            if events[i] > threshold:
                sessions_array += events[left_edge:i]
                left_edge = i
                threshold = events[i] + 5
        return sessions_array
    return []
```

...but I'd strongly prefer not to admit defeat and sacrifice the performance. Unfortunately, I think I need recursion here, and that's not supported.